# Crop the border of a div based on a svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to crop / change the border of a div based on a svg (assume the blue pencil in the drawing is the svg).

I tried to use [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/mask) but it's not what I want because I also want to display the SVG.

Of course transparency is key because the background below the div is different.

[image: Drawing of what I want to accomplish]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using CSS and SVG clip paths, although it's hard to work with and has low browser support. Below is an example to get you started.

```css
.clipped-card {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#curved-bottom);
  clip-path: url(#curved-bottom);
  background: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.clipped-card-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.clipped-card svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="curved-bottom" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M0 0H1V.9C.92.83.73.74.5.9A.6.6 90 00.49.91C.27 1.07.07.98 0 .91V0Z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="clipped-card">
  <div class="clipped-card-content">
    My content
  </div>
  <svg fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 24"><path d="M0 10v5c7 7 27 16 49 0a60 60 0 001-1c23-16 42-7 50 0v1-5-1C92 2 73-7 50 9a60 60 0 00-1 1C27 26 7 17 0 10z" fill="red"/></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm it's using the SVG as the path to crop, so it's part of what I want, but I **also** want to display the svg where it's cropped (imagine the svg is 5 pixels width).

Comment: You can display the SVG just by adding it to the content and pushing it to the bottom using CSS positioning. You can then make sure the ratios are the same by using CSS and an inner element for the content. See my updated answer.

Comment: I see, so you use two SVGs but one with the clipPath tag.
I'll need to update my SVG so I have the space above, not just the "thick line"...